# outer join in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I did searches for oracle sql outer joins to see whether there is a shotcut (like I think in mysql you can do where a *= b I believe, which could do an outer join).  I found one thing that looked promising but didn't work.  I am trying to find a shortcut because I can never remember the outer join syntax.  I have to look it up all the time.  Take this for example:

```
SELECT
  l.*,
  r.*
FROM database.login l LEFT OUTER JOIN database.relation r
    ON l.user_id = r.user_id
       AND r.user_id IS NULL
```

Several values of r.user_id were null as expected.  I tried what I read somewhere:

```
SELECT
  l.*,
  r.*
FROM database.login l, database.relation r
WHERE l.user_id = +r.user_id
```

but that did not select rows from database.relation that did not have a user_id matching database.login.

So do you have to type that whole syntax?  I am trying to get an entry in login not in relation.

I suppose I could use something like the following:

```
u.user_id not in select user_id from database.relation
```

if necessary

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the first query?

Comment: In my humble opinion, you should take the time to learn the ANSI join syntax. It's not exactly difficult: `select * from some_table <join type> some_other_table <on join condition(s)>`. You just have to know which join type to use, that go with your join conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
select l.*, r.*
from database.login l, database.relation r
where l.user_id = r.user_id (+)
```

for left outer join and

```
select l.*, r.*
from database.login l, database.relation r
where l.user_id (+) = r.user_id
```

for right outer join

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to **not** use the `(+)` operator any more.

Comment: Yet, it is a way to implement outer joins with a shorter syntax. I am using this all the time, and have never encountered an issue. It is ok to use it if it used careful.

Comment: @Nemanja91 You obviously haven't tried to do a join like `SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 (+) AND t2.col2 (+) = t3.col1;`, because that gives you `ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table` whereas `SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1) RIGHT OUTER JOIN t3 ON (t2.col2 = t3.col1);` works just fine!

Comment: Works, but does not make much sense to do this kind of queries